# "Ship" won't move for "Asteroid Avoidance" game

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I apologize in advance if what I say makes little to no sense, I am still new to Javascript coding.

I am trying to create a "Asteroid Avoidance" game, using the Javascript code taken from Chapter 9 of "Foundation: HTML5 Canvas for Games and Environment". My issue is I can not get the "player's ship" to move. it seems locked in place in the upper left corner of the screen. I can not figure out how to get the ship to move even though I have variables for the key codes and what to do for the "keyup" and "keydown".

I am not getting any syntax errors, so I am guessing I have code in the wrong place, I am just not sure where. If I may ask, can I get an extra pair of eyes to be able to see where I went wrong?

Here is the jsbin (http://jsbin.com/dunaxakifu/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var canvas = $("#gameCanvas");
 var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
 
 //Canvas Dimension
 var canvasWidth = canvas.width();
 var canvasHeight = canvas.height();
 
 //Game Settings
 var playGame;
 
 var asteroids;
 var numAsteroids;
 
 var player;
 
 //Scoring
 var score;
 var scoreTimeout;
 
 //Key codes
 var arrowUp = 38;
 var arrowRight = 39;
 var arrowDown = 40;
 
 //Game UI
 var ui = $("#gameUI");
 var uiIntro = $("#gameIntro");
 var uiStats = $("#gameStats");
 var uiComplete = $("#gameComplete");
 var uiPlay = $("#gamePlay");
 var uiReset = $(".gameReset");
 var uiScore = $(".gameScore");
 
 var soundBackground = $("#gameSoundBackground").get(0);
 var soundThrust = $("#gameSoundThrust").get(0);
 var soundDeath = $("#gameSoundDeath").get(0);
 
 
 var Asteroid = function(x, y, radius, vX){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.vX = vX;
 };
 
 var Player = function(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = 24;
  this.height = 24;
  this.halfWidth = this.width/2;
  this.halfHeight = this.height/2;
  
  this.vX = 0;
  this.vY = 0;
 
  this.moveRight = false;
  this.moveUp = false;
  this.moveDown = false;
  
  this.flameLength = 20;
 };
 
 
 //Reset and start the game
 function startGame() {
  //Reset game stats
  uiScore.html("0");
  uiStats.show();
  
  asteroids = new Array();
  numAsteroids = 10;
  


  score = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++){
   var radius = 5+(Math.random()*10);
   var x = canvasWidth+radius+Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasWidth);
   var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasHeight);
   var vX = -5-(Math.random()*5);
   
   asteroids.push(new Asteroid(x, y, radius, vX));
  };
  
  player = new Player(150, canvasHeight/2);
  
  //Set up initial game settings
  playGame = false;
  
  //Keyboard events
  $(window).keydown(function(e){
   var keyCode = e.keyCode;
   
   if (!playGame){
    playGame = true;
    soundBackground.currentTime = 0;
    soundBackground.play();
    animate();
    timer();
   };
   
   if (keyCode == arrowRight){
    player.moveRight = true;
   } else if (keyCode == arrowUp){
    player.moveUp = true;
   } else if (keyCode == arrowDown){
    player.moveDown = true;
   };
   
   if (soundThrust.paused){
    soundThrust.currentTime = 0;
    soundThrust.play();
   };
  });
  $(window).keyup(function(e){
   var keyCode = e.keyCode;
   
   if (keyCode == arrowRight){
    player.moveRight = false;
   } else if (keyCode == arrowUp){
    player.moveUp = false;
   } else if (keyCode == arrowDown){
    player.moveDown = false;
   };
   
   soundThrust.pause();
   
  });
  
  //Start the animation loop
  animate();
 };
 
 //Initialize the game environment
 function init() {
  uiStats.hide();
  uiComplete.hide();
  
  uiPlay.click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   uiIntro.hide();
   startGame();
  });

  $(window).unbind("keyup");
  $(window).unbind("keydown");
  
  uiReset.click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   uiComplete.hide();
   startGame();
   soundThrust.pause();
   soundBackground.pause();
   clearTimeout(scoreTimeout);
  });
 };
 
 //Timer
 function timer(){
  if(playGame){
   scoreTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    uiScore.html(++score);
    if (score % 5 == 0) {
     numAsteroids += 5;
    };
    timer();
   }, 1000);
  };
 };
 
 //Animation loop that does all the fun stuff
 function animate(){
  //Clear
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  
  
  var asteroidsLength = asteroids.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < asteroidsLength; i++){
   var tmpAsteroid = asteroids[i];
   
   var dX = player.x - tmpAsteroid.x;
   var dY = player.y - tmpAsteroid.y;
   var distance = Math.sqrt((dX*dY)+(dY*dY));
 
   if (distance < player.halfWidth+tmpAsteroid.radius){
    soundThrust.pause();
  
    soundDeath.currentTime = 0;
    soundDeath.play();
  
    //Game over
    playGame = false;
    clearTimeout(scoreTimeout);
    uiStats.hide();
    uiComplete.show();
  
    soundBackground.pause();
  
    $(window).unbind("keyup");
    $(window).unbind("keydown");
   };
   
   if(tmpAsteroid.x+tmpAsteroid.radius < 0){
    tmpAsteroid.radius = 5+(Math.random()*10);
    tmpAsteroid.x = canvasWidth+tmpAsteroid.radius;
    tmpAsteroid.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasHeight);
    tmpAsteroid.vX = -5-(Math.random()*5);
   };
   
   tmpAsteroid.x += tmpAsteroid.vX;
   
   context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(tmpAsteroid.x, tmpAsteroid.y, tmpAsteroid.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
   context.closePath();
   context.fill();
   
   player.vX = 0;
   player.vY = 0;
   if (player.moveRight){
    player.vX = 3;
   } else {
    player.vX = -3;
   };
   if (player.moveUp){
    player.vy = 3;
   };
   if (player.moveDown){
    player.vy = 3;
   };
   
   player.x = player.vX;
   player.y = player.vY;
   
   if (player.moveRight){
    context.save();
    context.translate(player.x-player.halfWidth, player.y);
    
    if (player.flameLength == 20) {
     player.flameLength = 15;
    } else {
     player.flameLength = 20;
    };
   };
   
   if (player.x-player.halfWidth < 20){
    player.x = 20+player.halfWidth;
   } else if (player.x+player.halfWidth > canvasWidth-20) {
    player.x = canvasWidth-20-player.halfWidth;
   }
   if (player.y-player.halfHeight < 20){
    player.y = 20+player.halfHeight;
   } else if (player.y+player.halfHeight > canvasHeight-20) {
    player.y = canvasHeight-20-player.halfHeight;
   };
   
   context.fillStyle = "orange";
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(0, -5);
   context.lineTo(-player.flameLength, 0);
   context.lineTo(0, 5);
   context.closePath();
   context.fill();
   
   context.restore();
   
   context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(player.x+player.halfWidth, player.y);
   context.lineTo(player.x-player.halfWidth, player.y-player.halfHeight);
   context.lineTo(player.x-player.halfWidth, player.y+player.halfHeight);
   context.closePath();
   context.fill();
   
   while (asteroids.length < numAsteroids){
    var radius = 5+(Math.random()*10);
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasWidth)+canvasWidth+radius;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvasHeight);
    var vX = -5-(Math.random()*5);
    
    asteroids.push(new Asteroid(x, y, radius, vX));
   };
  };
  
  if (playGame){
   //run the animation loop again in 33 milliseconds
   setTimeout(animate, 33);
  };
 };
 
 init();
 
});
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
canvas {
 display:block;
}
body{
 background:#000;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
}
h1{
 font-size:30px;
}
h6{
 font-size:15px;
}
p{
 margin:0 20px;
}
a{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
a.button{
 background:#185da8;
 border-radius:5px;
 display:block;
 font-size:30px;
 margin:40px 0 0 270px;
 padding:10px;
 width:200px;
 text-align:center;
}
a.button:hover{
 background:#2488f5;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#game{
 height:600px;
 left:50%;
 margin:-300px 0 0 -400px;
 position:relative;
 top:50%;
 width:980px;
}
#gameCanvas{
 background:#001022;
 border:5px solid green;
 background-image:url(../images/space.jpg);
 background-position:center top;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
#gameUI{
 height:600px;
 position:absolute;
 width:980px;
}
#gameIntro, #gameComplete {
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 margin-top: 100px;
 padding:40px 0;
 text-align:center;
}
#gameStats{
 font-size:14px;
 margin:20px 0;
}
#gameStats .gameReset{
 margin:20px 20px 0 0;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Debris Fields of Spiral Galaxy</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2-1-4min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="game">
  <div id="gameUI">
   <div id="gameIntro">
    <h1>Debris Fields of Spiral Galaxy</h1>
    <h6>A <i>Galaxy Smuggler's Run</i> Game</h6>
    <p>Click "Play" and then press any key to start.</p>
    <p><a id="gamePlay" class="button" href="">Play!</a></p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameStats">
    <p>Time: <span class="gameScore"></span> seconds</p>
    <p><a class="gameReset" href="">Reset</a></p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameComplete">
    <h1>Game Over!</h1>
    <p>You survived for <span class="gameScore"></span> seconds.</p>
    
    <p><a class="gameReset button" href="">Play Again?</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="980" height="600">
  
  </canvas>
  <audio id="gameSoundBackground" loop>
   <source src="sounds/background.ogg">
   <source src="sounds/background.mp3">
  </audio>
  <audio id="gameSoundThrust" loop>
   <source src="sounds/thrust.ogg">
   <source src="sounds/thrust.mp3">
  </audio>
  <audio id="gameSoundDeath">
   <source src="sounds/death.ogg">
   <source src="sounds/death.mp3">
  </audio>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of code there, try calling the movement functions directly on the Player object

```
Player.prototype.moveUp = function() {
    this.y++;   
}
Player.prototype.moveDown = function() {
    this.y--;   
}

$(window).keyDown(function(key) {
    if(key == x) {
        Player.moveUp();
    }
    else if (key == y) {
        Player.moveDown();
    }
});
```

Not sure this will make a difference at all, its just the way I do it :B

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the only problem but in your animation loop you are using `player.vY` and `player.vy` (note the difference in upper/lowercase 'Y').

Also in the animation loop player.vy seems to be given the same value for up and down

```
if (player.moveUp){
    player.vy = 3;
};
if (player.moveDown){
    player.vy = 3;
};
```

And I am not sure but I thought I saw `if(player.moveDown)` (again in the code above) evaluate to true when I hit the right arrow. I didnt look further to see if this was intentional/ desired or the result of hitting arrow down before right arrow and perhaps `moveDown` was not reset etc.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the vY corrections. I am sure that was causing some problems. I also set the move down to -3. do you think that should fix it? I am still having issues, with the movement, I do have class for HTML tomorrow so I will ask my professor where I may have gone wrong, I think what I will also do is try to put the player movements in a separate Javascript file and link it in my HTML to see if I can isolate it that way.